# 1 or 0 instead the data in database php/jq

Tags: php

I create a form. It works but the php code put the "1" or "0" in database 
instead of the data. I copy just a "nome field to the question

This chk validate  in jq and wirks:

```
    $('#nome').bind( 'blur', function(){
    var a= $(this).val();
    if(a == "" || a.length<=2 ){
    $('#chkName' ).addClass("invalid").removeClass("valid"); 
    } else{ 
    $('#chkName' ).addClass("valid").removeClass("invalid");
      }      
       })
```

//PGP code
set the vars:

```
 $nome= isset($_POST['nome']);
```

ecc......

html form:

```
<input type="text"  id="nome" placeholder="nome" style="height:30px;width:250px; " name="nome" />
```

and this post post the contents in DB:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if(empty($_POST['nome']) || empty($_POST['cognome']) || empty($_POST['nascita']) || 
empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['pass'] )|| empty($_POST['gender'] )|| 
empty($_POST['city'] )) {

die($error= " Form error chk !");

}



 $sql="INSERT INTO users (Nome,Cognome, Password, Data_Creazione,Ora_Creazione, Email, DataDiNascita, Gender, Visible ,City)
  VALUES ('$nome','$cognome' ,'$pass','$data','$ora', 'email' , '$nascita','$gender','$visible','$city')";

 if($db->query($sql)){


     echo "Thans  " .$nome . "<br />"." Hello! ";

       }            


     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
$nome= isset($_POST['nome']) ?  $_POST['nome'] : '';
```

instead of:

```
$nome= isset($_POST['nome']);
```

Isset just checks that the value is set. It doesn't actually read the value.